# Mensagens de erros ou Exceptions devem ser formatadas?

Tags: suporte

Mensagens onde é informado um erro ou uma `Exception` devem ser formatadas? Por exemplo:

> "error: unknown type name ‘minhavariavel’ in main function"

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code"
```

Mais por questões de visualização mesmo. Quando algum usuário posta uma mensagem informando qual erro está dando ao compilar um código. É necessário que seja formatada ou isso é irrelevante?

Comment: Não entendi o voto para fechar. Dúvidas referentes a comunidade no geral não devem ser tiradas no Meta?

Comment: Eu votei por engano, me desculpe. No [guia de estilo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/91) fala que pode ser usado a 'citação' para mensagens de erros, talvez para uma exception longa seja melhor o bloco de código.

Comment: Obrigado, resolvido.